# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied Post, Put in EF core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I create WebAPI using Entity framework core. I have checked under Local, the Get, Put, Post commands work fine. I upload the source to the Server. Everything seems fine. However when I execute the Post, Put command, I get an error: `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied`. The Get command works normally.

[image]

Please help with the solution. Thank you!